# InlineHelpText with Fieldset and pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce, fieldsets

I have the following Visualforce

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myObject}" var="obj">

    <!-- iterate over the fieldset to render the columns -->
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.myObject.FieldSets.FieldSetName}" var="field">
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:outputText styleClass="header" value="{!field.Label}" />
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:inputField value="{!myObject[field]}" />
        </apex:column>
    </apex:repeat>

</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Each of the fields in the fieldset has help text, but the help text does not appear in the Visualforce page. According to the response to [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jELVAA2), help text should be automatic if using inputField, but I do not get help text at all, either in the column headers or next to the inputs.

How can I get the standard inline help text to work in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that you can't get help text in this scenario. I believe it automatically renders only when InputField is used in the context of a PageBlockSection (where the label and input field are rendered automatically, with the help bubble in between). I haven't seen a way to get mouseover help bubbles automatically in a PageBlockTable. The solution would be some sort of (ugly) roll-your-own.

Comment: I wrote something up on how to copy Salesforce's implementation of the help text if you go down the path of rolling your own - http://michaelwelburn.com/2014/01/13/customization-of-salesforce-com-help-text-bubbles-in-visualforce/

Comment: @MichaelWelburn I'm always very wary of utilizing solutions like yours for the very reasons you mention. I've landed on using an image with a title attribute which takes longer to display that the native Salesforce hover help.